# When is $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$ cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the group of units $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$ always cyclic? Do we need that $n$ is a prime or something?

Comment: Because of $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$ has divisor of zero if and only if $n$ is composed, this group is cyclic if and only if $n$ is prime.

Comment: @Piquito: $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$ is a group, not a ring; it has no zero divisors.

Comment: @Piquito what about $(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^* \cong \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: @Piquito That is false. The group $\;\left(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z\right)^*\;$ is cyclic iff $\;n=1,2,4,p^k, 2p^k\;$ , with $\;p\;$ an odd prime, $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$

Comment: How hard is that to prove, @DonAntonio ? Do you care to sketch a proof for me? Could you give me a reference?

Comment: @MyNameIs Try this one: http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/lec07.pdf There are thousands of different sources in the web and also in books.

Answer (score 2):

It is cyclic for $n=4$ and for $n=p^k$  with $p$ an odd prime, $k\geq1$.
(read books on number theory, e.g. Ireland and Rosen.)

For $n=8$ check that the unit group consists of $\{1,3,5,7\}$ with operation being multiplication  mod $8$. Each number is its own inverse and hence no element of order 4 in this group (So this is isomorphic to Klein's group).

EDIT: This list  is incomplete. See the comment of DonAntonio below.

Comment: ...and for $\;n=1,2, p^k\;$ , with $\;p\;$ an odd integer and $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ .

Comment: Thanks for adding the missing cases!

Comment: That should have been $\;n=1,2,2p^k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ . My pleasure.